# While simulating a bouncing particle, slightly different maximum times yield wildly different intermediate results. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am attempting to simulate a particle bouncing around in a box with walls that move with a given velocity law (for now taken to be sawtooth) and recording the energy of the particle as a function of time. Though I have made some approximations that aren't entirely accurate (which I will expand on in my code samples) I am running into an issue where slightly different maximum times yield wildly different results below the maximum time when I expect the results to agree (see figures: in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FClf3.png) figure, the maximum time is 200 while in [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUYjA.png) it is 201. These figures are from a two-dimensional version of the code, though the problem persists even in one dimension).

In a one-dimensional setting, my attempt proceeds as follows;

First, I set the minimum time, maximum time, and time step then generate an array of times that ranges from the minimum to the maximum time in intervals of the time step:

```
TMin = 0;
TMax = 200;
TimeStep = .0001;
times = linspace(TMin,TMax,(TMax-TMin)/TimeStep);
```

As far as I can tell, this step is working to correctly produce the array of times that I would like. Next I generate arrays for the position and velocity of the particle of the same size as the time array;

```
x = zeros(1,TNum(2));
vx = zeros(1,TNum(2));
```

At this step I also set initial conditions for the particle. Next I set parameters for the oscillations of the walls, including amplitude and frequencies, to define the velocity law, for exaple

```
VLeft = ALeft*FLeft*sawtooth(FLeft.*times+SLeft)
```

where VLeft is the velocity of the left wall, ALeft is the amplitude of the position oscillation, FLeft is the frequency of oscillation, and SLeft is a phase shift with respect to the other wall. As far as I can tell, this step is also doing what I want it to. Next, I set the initial conditions for the wall and generate the positions of the wall from the velocity law using a Riemann sum approximation;

```
Left(1)=-1; %For example...
for i=2:TNum(2)
    Left(i)=Left(i-1)+VLeft(i).*(TimeStep);
end
```

This seems to generate the correct form for the position of the wall as a function of time so long as I use a small enough value for TimeStep (which is what I would expect based on how I'm doing the computation). A similar kind of time evolution is done for the right wall.

The next step is where I try to generate the position and velocity of the particle as a function of time and I think this must be where something is going wrong.

```
for i=2:TNum(2)

    x(i)=x(i-1)+vx(i-1)*(TimeStep);%distance=velocity*time

    if x(i) < Right(i) && x(i) > Left(i) 
    vx(i)=vx(i-1); %If it doesn't hit a wall, velocity doesn't change
    end

    if x(i) < Left(i) || x(i) == Left(i) %If it hits the left wall, bounce off
    vx(i)=-vx(i-1)+VLeft(i);
    x(i) = Left(i)+abs(x(i)-Left(i));
    end

    if x(i) > Right(i) || x(i) == Right(i) %If it hits the right wall, bounce off
    vx(i)=-vx(i-1)+VRight(i);
    x(i) = Right(i)-abs(Right(i)-x(i));
    end
end
```

For the collisions, I am assuming that the walls are infinitely massive. The approximation that I know is incorrect is that if the position of the particle is beyond that of the wall that I can simply reverse its position with respect to the wall and give it the appropriate velocity -- to actually calculate where it would be, I would have to calculate the exact collision time somehow. This seems like it's the only place where the issue could be happening, but I don't see how this would cause a change in maximum time to alter results below the maximum time.

Finally I calculate the energy as

```
Energy = zeros(1,TNum(2));

for i=1:TNum(2)
    Energy(i)=vx(i)^2+vy(i)^2;
end
```

What I really can't understand is why the change in maximum time for the same time step would yield such different results. Decreasing the time step increases the region in which the results match, but if I understand what the code is doing correctly then an increase in the maximum time shouldn't change anything about what happened at the lower times since the values of the times array are the same up until that point.

I apologize that this question is so long-winded and general, but I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here and would like to provide as much information as possible.

Edit: I've added the full code for the two-dimensional version below.

```
%--------- THE TIME BLOCK ------------------------------------------------%

TMin = 0;
TMax = 201;
TimeStep = .001;
TDensity = (TMax-TMin)/TimeStep; %Declare instance variables that determine the time steps

times = linspace(TMin,TMax,TDensity); %Generate the array of time steps

 TNum = size(times); %For looping purposes and generating velocity, position arrays


%-------- THE OBJECT INITIAL CONDITIONS BLOCK-----------------------------%

Lx = 1; %Half the length of the box, which spans from -Lx to Lx
Ly = 1; %Half the width of the box, from -Ly to Ly

x0 = 0; %Initial x position
v0x = .1; %Initial x velocity
y0 = 0; %Initial y position
v0y = .1; %Initial y velocity

x = zeros(1,TNum(2));
vx = zeros(1,TNum(2)); %Initialize the arrays for position and velocity
y = zeros(1,TNum(2));
vy = zeros(1,TNum(2));

%------ WALL INITIAL CONDITIONS BLOCK ------------------------------------%

ALeft = 0.15; %Determines the size of the oscillations
ARight = 0.2;
ATop = 0.25;
ABottom = 0.12;

FLeft = 1; %Frequencies
FRight = 0.2;
FTop = 3;
FBottom = 0.2;


SLeft = pi/2; %Phase _S_hifts
SRight = 0;

STop = pi/2;
SBottom = 0;

Left = zeros(1,TNum(2));
Right = zeros(1,TNum(2));
Top = zeros(1,TNum(2));
Bottom = zeros(1,TNum(2));

VLeft = ALeft*FLeft*sawtooth(FLeft.*times+SLeft);
VRight = ARight*FRight*sawtooth(FRight.*times+SRight);
VTop = ATop*FTop*sawtooth(FTop.*times+STop);
VBottom = ABottom*FBottom*sawtooth(FBottom.*times+SBottom);

%---- TIME TO MOVE -------------------------------------------------------%

x(1)=x0; %Set the initial conditions for the variable arrays
y(1)=y0;
vx(1)=v0x;
vy(1)=v0y;
Left(1)=-Lx;
Right(1)=Lx;
Top(1)=Ly;
Bottom(1)=-Ly;

for i=2:TNum(2)
    Left(i)=Left(i-1)+(1/2)*TimeStep*(VLeft(i-1)+VLeft(i)); 
    Right(i)=Right(i-1)+(1/2)*TimeStep*(VRight(i-1)+VRight(i));
    Top(i)=Top(i-1)+(1/2)*TimeStep*(VTop(i-1)+VTop(i));
    Bottom(i)=Bottom(i-1)+(1/2)*TimeStep*(VBottom(i-1)+VBottom(i));
end

for i=2:TNum(2)

    x(i)=x(i-1)+vx(i-1)*(TimeStep);%distance=velocity*time
    y(i)=y(i-1)+vy(i-1)*(TimeStep);

    if x(i) < Right(i) && x(i) > Left(i) %If it doesn't hit a wall, velocity doesn't change
        vx(i)=vx(i-1);
    end

    if y(i) < Top(i) && y(i) > Bottom(i) %If it doesn't hit a wall, velocity doesn't change
        vy(i)=vy(i-1);
    end

    if x(i) < Left(i) %If it hits the left wall, bounce off
        vx(i)=-vx(i-1)+VLeft(i);
        x(i) = Left(i)+abs(x(i)-Left(i));
    end

    if x(i) > Right(i) %If it hits the right wall, bounce off
        vx(i)=-vx(i-1)+VRight(i);
        x(i) = Right(i)-abs(Right(i)-x(i));
    end

    if y(i) < Bottom(i) %If it hits the bottom wall, bounce off
        vy(i)=-vy(i-1)+VBottom(i);
        y(i) = Bottom(i)+abs(y(i)-Bottom(i));
    end

    if y(i) > Top(i) %If it hits the top wall, bounce off
        vy(i)=-vy(i-1)+VTop(i);
        y(i) = Top(i)-abs(Top(i)-y(i));
    end
end

Energy = zeros(1,TNum(2));

for i=1:TNum(2)
    Energy(i)=vx(i)^2+vy(i)^2;
end

% figure
% plot(x,y);
% title('Particle Trajectory')
% xlabel('X Position')
% ylabel('Y Position')

% figure
% subplot(2,1,1)
% plot(times,x);
% hold on
% plot(times,Right);
% plot(times,Left);
% ylabel('X Position')
% title('One-Dimensional Positions of Particle and Walls')
% subplot(2,1,2)
% plot(times, y);
% hold on
% plot(times,Top);
% plot(times,Bottom);
% xlabel('Time')
% ylabel('Y Position')



figure
plot(times,Energy);
axis([0 200 0 80])
title('Particle Energy (v^2)')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Energy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TMin = 0;
TMax = 200;
TimeStep = .0001;
times = linspace(TMin,TMax,(TMax-TMin)/TimeStep);

TMin = 0;
TMax = 201;
TimeStep = .0001;
times_2 = linspace(TMin,TMax,(TMax-TMin)/TimeStep);

all(times(1:2000000) == times_2(1:2000000))
```

> > ans =
> >
> > ```
> > 0
> > ```

So, because of rounding error, the first 2,000,000 values of times are not exactly equal to the corresponding values of times_2. The discrepancy varies from about 10^-13 (for values near the start) to 10^-4 for the last few values.

Now, since you have not provided the exact values of the wall oscillation frequencies, it is difficult to tell what is happening, but I suspect it is part of the kinematics of the problem. It should be quite interesting to figure out. Perhaps you could post the full code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't recall the exact set of parameters I used for the two images I posted, but the problem persists for a variety of parameters. I have posted the full two-dimensional code that I'm currently working with. I switched from a Riemann sum for the integration to trapezoidal rule but that hasn't significantly changed anything.

Comment: Also, I should add that I really appreciate you pointing out to me that `linspace` wasn't working like I thought -- I've sinced utilized a loop to explicitly fill the time array with values, so the original problem has been resolved. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for posting the code. I am pretty sure (as you had already suspected) that it is the discretization of the time and reflection point that is the issue. But it is certainly very interesting. The graph makes a sudden change about half way through. I suppose this "transition point" can be varied by tuning the wall frequencies appropriately. If I were you, I would do a quick write up of this effect and file it as it is a phenomenon by itself.

Comment: clarification: Discretization of the time and reflection point, coupled of course with the minute changes in the times.